# how can i add zero at the fist and end of all an array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have an array like this:

```
contact_map = array([[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
   ...,
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

which each element of that is something like this:

```
contact_map[19] = array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.,
   1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
```

len(contact_map) = 224

len(contact_map[19]) =100

I want to change all elements of contact_map in such a way to add "0" at the first and end of each element, for example changing contact_map[19] into:

```
contact_map[19] = array([0.,1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.,
   1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0,.])
```

len(contact_map[19]) = 102

and so on, for contact_map[0], contact_map[1], ....

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you not use arr.insert(index, value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) like below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1., 1., 1. , 1., 1., 1.],
                  [1., 1., 0. , 0., 1., 1.], 
                  [0., 1., 0. , 0., 1., 1.]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 6)

>>> out = np.pad(a, [(0,0), (1, 1)], 'constant', constant_values=0)  
# pad first dimension ^^^    ^^^
#                            ^^^ pad second dimension 
#                                (first num for set how many pad at first
#                                 second num for ... at last.)                 
>>> out.shape
(3,8)

>>> out
array([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Your Input:

```
contact_map = np.random.randint(0,2 , (224, 100))
print(len(contact_map))
# 224
print(len(contact_map[19]))
# 100
contact_map = np.pad(contact_map, [(0,0), (1, 1)], 'constant', constant_values=0)
print(len(contact_map[19]))
# 102
print(len(contact_map[0]))
# 102
```